# Can not run CGI program on my VPS

Tags: python, linux, apache

I have linux VPS on which i tried to find out httpd.conf to check settings and to deploy my test CGI script. I found following list httpd.conf :

```
/home/cpeasyapache/src/httpd-2.2/docs/conf/httpd.conf
/home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache/tests/regression/server_root/conf/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf/original/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf_pre_ea3/original/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf_pre_ea3/httpd.conf
```

Which one should i consider ? however i checked into :

```
/home/cpeasyapache/src/httpd-2.2/docs/conf/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

where i can see the :

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So as per the setting i write my test.py and chmod 755 test.py and try to run from my browser :

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-bin/test.py

But i am not able to print "hello test" as inside the script i have given a print statement.

I am getting "500 Internal Server Error" . I am new in this field .

Could anybody please help me on this .

Comment: Note : i placed my script in : /usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/

Comment: Check your error_log... it will be significantly easier than guessing :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Options, try this:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin">
    Options +ExecCGI
```